# Consulta con operador ternario C#

Tags: c#

Se me pidió explicar el siguiente código en una prueba de programador en lenguaje C#:

```
var value= this.Customer?.GetName()?? string.empty;
```

No se me daba más explicación, así que mi respuesta fue:

> es un operador ternario en el que si existe una instancia de la clase
>   Customer entonces voy al método GetName() de la clase Customer y
>   guardo el valor en la variable value, pero en caso de no existir
>   entonces guardo un string vacío.

Lo interesante es que me dijeron que no era correcto. No soy un experto pero no encuentro en qué falle ¿podrían indicarme mi error? Como les repito, sólo me presentan la línea de código y me piden que la explique.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Intentaré dar una explicación lo mas "entendible" que pueda:

En principio `this.Customer` puede ser una Clase estática o una instancia de Clase, aun así no importa para la explicación.

El operador **`?.`** indica que obtendrá el método `GetName()` siempre y cuando `this.Customer` **no sea NULL**. Esto se hace para que **no se lance una excepción** al acceder al método `GetName()` si `this.Customer` **es NULL**.

En este caso (si `this.Customer` es igual a **NULL**) la expresión `this.Customer?.GetName()`**devolverá NULL** (y no una excepción del tipo `NullReferenceException`).

Y por último, el operador **`??`** es un condicional que asignará el valor `string.empty` a `var value`, si el resultado de `this.Customer?.GetName()` **es NULL**.

---

**Conclusión:** La variable `var value` sera igual a `string.empty` cuando el método `this.Customer?.GetName()` **devuelva NULL**. En caso contrario `var value` tomará del valor del método `this.Customer.GetName()`.

Comment: Hola, quisiera agregar, ?. es el "Elvis Operator" el cual evalúa el término a continuación de este solamente si el término anterior a este no es null, a este "Elvis op" se le agrego el "coalescing operator" el cual evalúa si el termino anterior es null entonces asigno el término siguiente, la respuesta es correcta, si this.customer no es null entonces voy al metodo GetName sino devuelvo null, solo queria especificar el nombre de los operadores.